# IIS site created under default website is not loading

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I created a simple webapi application and created an application inside Default website in IIS.
eg; created the application named 'test.web'

when i try to access `http://localhost/test.web` the page is not loading and giving 500 error.

Can anyone point me what am i missing?

when i try to access only http://localhost it shows the default iis page. only the application created under default website is not loading up

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the ASP.Net module in 'Add and remove features' in IIS solved the issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules